# I am getting a raise key error in my python script. How can I resolve this?

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

I am hoping someone can help me with this. After having a nightmare installing numpy on a raspberry pi, I am stuck again!
The gist of what I am trying to do is I have an arduino, that sends numbers (bib race numbers entered by hand) over lora, to the rx of the raspberry pi.
This script is supposed to read the incoming data, - it prints so I can see it in the terminal. Pandas is then supposed to compare the number against a txt/csv file, and if it matches in the bib number column it is supposed to append the matched row to a new file.
Now, The first bit works (capturing the data and printing) and on my windows PC, the 2nd bit works when I was testing with a fixed number rather than incoming data.
I have basically tried my best to mash them together to get the incoming number to compare instead.

I should also state that the error happened after I pressed 3 on the arduino (which then printed on the terminal of the raspberry pi before erroring), so probably why it is keyerror 3

My code is here

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import csv
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            print(line)
            with open ("test_data.csv","a") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
                writer.writerow([line])
                df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
                #out = (line)
                filtered_df = df[line]
            print('Original Dataframe\n---------------\n',df)
            print('\nFiltered Dataframe\n------------------\n',filtered_df)
            filtered_df.to_csv("data_amended.txt", mode='a', index=False, header=False)
#print(df.to_string())
```

And my error is here:

```
Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %Run piserialmashupv1.py
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '3'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/piserialmashupv1.py", line 20, in <module>
    filtered_df = df[line]
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3455, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: '3'

>>>
```

I had been asked to put the first few lines of *data.txt*

```
_id,firstname,surname,team,info
1, Peter,Smith,,Red Walk (70 miles- 14 mile walk/run + 56 mile cycle)
2, Samantha,Grey,Team Grey,Blue walk (14 mile walk/run)
3, Gary,Parker,,Red Walk (70 miles- 14 mile walk/run + 56 mile cycle)
```

I think it must be the way I am referencing the incoming rx number?

Any help very much appreciated!
Dave

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68749939/edit) including the first 3 lines of your *data.txt* (or a sample file that resembles it)?

Comment: Thanks @enzo I have added the data.txt. 
Also, I figured it all out (with a little help)

Fixed code is in the answer.
The new code ran, but didn't give me any filter data. 
This was because the data type I was reading from the RX I was saving as an integer, and I wasn't specifying that when doing the pandas filter, so it couldn't use it properly. 
You will also see I added in: _ser.write("Y".encode())_
This was because I had another script to send a ping to the arduino to show connection, but this was interfering with the receive, so I added it in as a response

Answer (score 0):

I have it working, see the final code below
I know that Pandas just didnt like the way the data was inputting originally.
This fixes it. I also had to ensure it knew it was dealing with an integer when filtering, as the first attempt I didn't, and it couldn't filter the data properly.

``
import serial
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            print(line)
            with open ("test_data.txt","w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
                writer.writerow([line])
                time.sleep(0.1)
                ser.write("Y".encode())
                df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
                out = df['_id'] == int(line)
                filtered_df = df[out]
                print('Original Dataframe\n---------------\n',df)
                print('\nFiltered Dataframe\n---------\n',filtered_df)
               filtered_df.to_csv("data_amended.txt", mode='a', 
    index=False, header=False)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

``